# Reading from file and initialising variable in Phoenix on server startup

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a large file with words that I want to read into a list on server startup. The list should then be available in a controller.

I figured the file reading should take place in lib/Appname.ex

- Where should the text file with words be placed? If I put it in web/static/assets how do I get the relative path to that location?
- Is it a viable approach to read the list into a module Attribute in the Appname.ex (in /lib)? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Can you explain a bit how do you plan to use the list in the controller?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. The point is to read a bunch of words into memory and be able to select a random word. What I did:

- Put the file with words in /web/static/assets
- Initialised a property in /lib/Appname.ex and made a method to get a random word:

`@words File.read!("web/static/assets/words.txt") |> String.split("\n")`

def word do
  @words |> Enum.random
end

- Called the method in the controller:

  `def index(conn, _params) do
  render conn, "index.html", word: Appname.word()
  end`

No idea if this is a good way to do it, but it works.